# aws credentials / policy to access only own resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have multiple stages (testing / staging / preview / production) of our java backend application using amazon web services.
Each stage creates and uses some SQS queues and SNS Topics, which it should also be able to delete. However, each stage should not be able to access the resources of each other.
How can I create aws credentials to represent that? I think that I should have a "user" (with access key / secret key) per stage. Each of these users should have full access to SQS / SNS but only on their own created resources. How can I do that?

I thought about using a name prefix in the queuename / topicname according the stage and then create a policy for each stage with a condition that arn must match ("like") that prefix:

[image: create policy]

However, it seems not to work and I am curious about the `Condition` and `Key`: There is a ArnLike condition and StringLike condition. If I take ArnLike, why I need to specify `Key`? the key should be the Arn... I probably do not understand the whole thing.

I think there must be an easy way to do what I need and I believe that I am digging in the wrong direction?!

Answer (score 0):

IAM policy `condition` is only available for selected set of [resources as shown here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/resources.html).

For example, you can [restrict user access S3 bucket prefix with their user name in there](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3-home-directory).  Since SQS and SNS currently are not part of it, so you cannot use IAM Policy with the "condition" to enable atomic restriction. 
You can only enable such policy with fine level restriction inside SQS and SNS services policy.